# How to made jQuery modal overlay to 100% transparent?

Tags: jquery

How could the jQuery modal overlay (dark transparent background) be made 100% transparent so that it doesn’t show at all on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `Opacity` option to 0.

```
$("#yourdialog").dialog({ 
        modal: true, 
        overlay: { 
            opacity: 0, 
            background: "black" 
        } 
    })
```

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: Side note: The `overlay` option is removed in 2010-ish.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this recently, the `overlay` option has been removed. You have to do it with a CSS override now

```
.ui-widget-overlay { 
   opacity: 0;
   filter:Alpha(Opacity=0); 
}
```

Or, if you want it just a little bit transparent, something like this

```
.ui-widget-overlay { 
   opacity: 0.2;
   filter:Alpha(Opacity=20); 
}
```